# can't update snapshot view in windows with some permision issue but from dynamic view it is ok to co/ci

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

this is not a problem with CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP but it is something different. I checked the dir of the file and has permision 775. Group is Ok. Some other people are having this problem as well. what might be the issue here?

Unable to load "".
Unable to copy "...." to "....": Permission denied.
Unable to load "".
Unable to copy "" to "": Permission denied.
Unable to load "".

Answer (score 1):

Once the update is done (and failed), you should do a

```
cd /path/to/parent/folder
cleartool ls
```

That will give you the status of that unloaded file.
Generally it is a process issue, like an anti virus which prevents the writing of a specific file it deems dangerous.

> do you know how to check if the vob storage is corrupted? Though I can access the storage location.

If the dynamic view access those files just fine, it isn't a vob storage issue.

You can see that error message as shown in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21407326):

```
Unable to remove "C:\views\view_tag\vob_tag\folder1\folder2":Permission Denied.
Unable to rename "C:\views\view_tag\vob_tag\folder1\folder2":Permission Denied.
It's possible that a process has 'C:\views\view_tag\vob_tag\folder1\folder2' open.
```

You can then use a [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to look for a sharing violation.

They mention (for old ClearCase version 7.0.1.6, 7.0.1.7, 7.1.0.2)

> The workaround for the issue is to close ClearCase Explorer and then reopen it.
>   You can then delete `folder1` and update the view without errors or retry deleting the view.

Comment: No file is loaded...while updating it goes through directories and while loading files, permission denied.

Comment: one thing: do you know how to check if the vob storage is corrupted? Though I can access the storage location.

Comment: @user2370590 I have edited my answer. I would rather check if there is a process keeping an handle on a resource (file or directory) that you are trying to update.