# not able to copy clearcase file from dynamic view , it hung and generates error

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Every time I try to copy clearcase file from view location to another location, it generates the following error:

```
The file cannot be opened because it is being used by another process. 
Please close all applications that might access this file and try again.
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

That explains probably your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20233355/6309): some process must keep an handle on the files you want to copy.

Try to close as many apps as you can, or even try that copy *just* after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a ClearCase issue. Its totally Windows one. You need not to close all apps to find the lock. try to install the "unlocker" application it will notify you what is locking your process

http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker

Enjoy,
Eli

Comment: @Eli, the link is not valid.